# how to open existing website in visual studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5

I use IIS 7.5 and VS2010.
I have an existing website which i would like to add to a solution.
I tried to open the website by using the option "open website" but the compilation failed:
I got hunderds of compilation errors indicating: missing "Imports System", "Imports System.Web", "IsNothing is not declared" and so on.

I would like to emphasize that it all worked well in VS2008 (!).
The website runs on .NET 3.5

Is there something i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Recently had the same problem migrating an app from IIS6 to IIS7.5

I ended up adding the missing "Imports System", "Imports System.Web", to the files referenced by the debugger.  Also added the missing variable declarations.

App worked without error after I made these changes, but I'm still not sure what IIS7 configuration caused this issue.

Comment: Well, this is not what I would like to do. Anyway I have solved it: The user which runs the application pool of the website in the IIS should have admin rights. Once you have this, you will be able to open the webiste from the visual studio (using the option of open existing website from the local IIS). Thank you anyway for your attention